# Data binding to custom object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a simple custom class (Person), which I want to bind to a label as a whole (not to separate properties of this class). The label should just present whatever the `Person.ToString()` returns (in this case FirstName + LastName).

1. How do I properly bind it using the person as a Source.
2. How do I make sure that any change in one of the properties of the Person will be reflected in the label?

---

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName {
        get { 
           return firstName; 
        }

        set {
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string lastName;

    public string LastName {
        get { 
            return lastName; 
        }

        set {
            lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() {           
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}

public Window1() {
myPerson = new Person() {
    FirstName = "AAA",
        LastName = "BBB"};

    InitializeComponent();
}

public Person MyPerson  {
    get { 
        return myPerson; 
    }

    set { 
        myPerson = value; 
    }
}

Label Content="{Binding Source=MyPerson}"
```

Comment: By the way, `Source=MyPerson` sets the binding source to the string `"MyPerson"`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new property `FullName` which returns the full name and raise `PropertyChanged` for `FullName` in the setters of `FirstName` and `LastName` as well. You should never bind to the object itself.

Comment: Agree with H.B. You can actually bind to the object it self, but you won't get change notifications.